# Transparent View over ImageView

Tags: android, view, transparent

I'm blocked there. I'm trying to put a transparent View over a background.
I've tried several methods.

throught XML with:

```
android:background="@color/transparent"
```

or

```
android:color="#80000000"
```

or putting a reference to color.xml file as so

```
<resources>
    <color name="transp">#80000000</color>
</resources>
```

with my layout.xml like this

```
android:background="@color/transp"
```

I've also tried to do it by generated code

```
myView.getBackground().setAlpha(45);
```

or

```
myViewm.setBackgroundResource(R.color.trans);
```

I've seen some posts related, but none of the answers worked.

Besides which is even stranger is that all of these solutions seems to wrok fine on the GraphicalLayout in Eclipse.
But when I launch my device, the screen remains not transparent.I've drawn a line on that view to make sure that something happens; and the line does show.

here is my layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/backgroundview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/space_bg"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc" />

      <View 
        android:id="@+id/tileview"        
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/><!-- 
        android:background="@color/transp"/>-->

</RelativeLayout>
```

and my code

```
private ImageView bg;
    MyView tV;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        tV = new MyView(this);

setContentView(tV);
```

}

and the myView onDraw

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)    
    {

        super.onDraw(canvas);
        this.setBackgroundResource(R.color.transp);
        canvas.drawLine(10,20,30,40, paint);

    }
```

So,  where am I wrong?
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
android:background="@color/transparent"
```

You can use the `transparent` color provided in android resources:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

> ---

```
android:color="#80000000"  

<resources>
    <color name="transp">#80000000</color>
</resources>

myViewm.setBackgroundResource(R.color.trans);
```

This will give you a very dark shade of gray. Alpha value of `80` is translucent at best.

> ---

```
myView.getBackground().setAlpha(45);
```

You may not be using this correctly.

> ---

```
private ImageView bg;
MyView tV;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                 WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    tV = new MyView(this);

    setContentView(tV);
}
```

This basically replaces the `View` inflated from `R.layout.activity_main`(which contains the ImageView and other widgets) with `MyView`. I don't think this is quite what you want. Try the following:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/backgroundview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/space_bg"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc" />

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/tileview"        
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/some_drawable_smaller_than_screen_size"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

How to inflate this xml:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                 WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

`id="@+id/tileview"` will be transparent and over `id="@+id/backgroundview"`.

Comment: Man...you're a generous genious!!!!...This f***g works! My mistake was it that I wanted to put a view over an imageView? Why did  not it work? And now, if I wanted to draw some lines over that view, could I do it by code?

Comment: @Antoine Glad it worked out. `And now, if I wanted to draw some lines over that view, could I do it by code?` << You'll have to be more specific than that. Do you want to draw some lines that are predefined over the ImageView (meaning: they appear when the activity starts)? Or, do you want to draw freestyle (using touch events) when your app is running?

Comment: Sorry, for being vague...I'd want to draw some lines displayed as soon as the activity starts, tiles actually with some events listener. And any explanation why my own solution did not work?

Comment: @Antoine Please go through my answer here: [Technique to make a canvas drawLine() clickable?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18275393/2558882). You _will_ need to make some changes: for example, you want the tiles to be clickable. For this, `linePath` will contain 4 sets of points(point1X, point1Y, point2X, point2Y, point3X, point3Y, point4X, point4Y). And `rectF` will enclose area within these points. Also consider posting a new question on this. Our discussion on this is off-topic with respect to the question posted here.

Comment: @ Vikram, I have a similar kind of issue. I used your code. Doesn't help me. Can you pls look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21414119/fadded-edge-to-imageview-in-android?noredirect=1#comment32305886_21414119

Comment: @Manikandan Hi. I have posted an answer to your question. I hope it helps. [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21517942/2558882)

Answer (score 8):

android:alpha="0.5"

0.0 is totally transparent, 0.5 is medium transparent  1.0 is fully opaque transparent.
**Here TextView is Transparent.

[image].[image]

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"[![enter image description here][2]][2]
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/img3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/home_tvshow_textView_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Your String"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/sp_17"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_110"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This is the most easy way to add semi overlay view. thanks

Answer (score 1):

- **Achieving with manual view**

If you're using Relative Layout as parent tag in your layout.

**You're layout should be like this..**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
.
.
.
    <View
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:background="#EBE9E9"
       android:id="@+id/hide_view"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**In Your Activity**

```
hide_view = findViewById(R.id.hide_view);
hide_view.setAlpha(0.5f);
```

Answer (score 0):

set in view of your widget

android:color="#80000000"