# How to Make Android BottomNavigationView Background Transparent?

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface

I have been trying to make the background of the `BottomNavigationView` transparent so that the background can be seen through it but when I try to set a background color with 0% alpha or a drawable with the same both programmatically and through xml, the background becomes like this:

BottomNavigationView Background with transparent colors:
[image]

I want the background completely transparent not like it is shown in the picture.

Here's the XML for the BottomNavigationView:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav"
    android:background="#00000000"
    app:itemBackground="#00000000"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/hintcolor"
    app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
    app:itemHorizontalTranslationEnabled="false"/>
```

Here's the Code for the Whole XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".NavigationDrawerActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:titleTextColor="?attr/text"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/appBarLayout"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="center"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
    <include layout="@layout/content_navigation_drawer"/>
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav"
        android:background="#00000000"
        app:itemBackground="#00000000"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/hintcolor"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:itemHorizontalTranslationEnabled="false"/>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't let me post pictures please copy paste the link for the picture.

Comment: Try the answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18320983/13031115)

Comment: Please add your XML layout to question.

Comment: @MdBasha i have tried that link, i have set both the backgroundcColor as well as itemBackgroundColor as transparent which gives the result as shown in the picture from the link in the post.

Comment: @Rajasekhar I have updated the answer with the XML for the BottomNavigationView, thanks

Comment: @SeyedShaheen Check my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That background overlay behind the title is because of elevation of bottom navaigtion bar. To remove it add this attribute.

```
app:elevation="0dp"
android:alpha="0.5"
```

Remove the background color which makes view transparent.

```
android:background="#00000000"
```

You can also try with

```
android:elevation="0dp"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this does not work, it does remove the shadow and the outline but the background becomes white, I'm looking for at least some level of transparency.

Comment: So you are telling you need scrollable background to be still visible behind the bottom navigation view to be partially visible not completely transparent with some elevation.

Comment: transparent or translucent anything is fine as long as i can see the background through the BottomNavigationView but right now the background is solid white even though the backgroundColor assigned is transparent and all the elevations are 0dp

Comment: Then all you have to set is alpha to 0.5 or lesser. Now i'm able to see the background where recyclerview is scrolling and visible partially. Also remove background color #00000000 which makes view completely transparent.

Comment: Setting the Alpha will set transparency for the entire view including the elements such as the buttons. What worked was your answers combined together, i set the Background Color and Item Background Color as transparent and reduced all the elevation to 0dp. The reason why it was solid white even after assigning transparent color was the margin separating the fragment and the bottom navigation view so the background in the fragment did not even reach the Bottom Navigation View. Thanks taking your time to reply and providing answer. Cheers.

Comment: In my case I used: app:elevation="0dp" android:alpha="1.0" because alpha set to 0.5 doesn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

navigationView.getBackground().setAlpha(122);
Here you can set the opacity between 0 (fully transparent) to 255 (completely opaque).

you can also use XML value alpha that takes double values.

The range is from 0f to 1f (inclusive), 0f being transparent and 1f being opaque:

android:alpha="0.0" invisible

android:alpha="0.5" see-through

android:alpha="1.0" full visible

Comment: Thanks for answering, Simply assigning a transparent color or setting the background alpha as you suggested works. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to get the solution needed using

```
app:elevation = "0dp"
```

or

```
android:background = "#0000000"
```

or

```
android:alpha = "0.0"
```

All of these solutions caused my icons to become transparent as well when going to a fragment with a background color other than white. I created a background.xml file for my BottomNavigationView and set it as the background and it works great. Below is my .xml code.

Transparent background xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#00000000"/>
</shape>
```

activity_layout.xml

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:background="@drawable/transparent_background"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but will help you for sure

**In your XML  file ( use as it is in your code later you can update as per your needs)**

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_margin="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded"
    app:elevation="4dp"
    app:itemIconSize="30dp"
    app:itemIconTint="#353535"
    app:itemTextColor="#353535"
    app:itemRippleColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="transparent_rect"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom" />
```

**Shape file:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#00000000"/></shape>
```