# Making canvas' drawline clickable

Tags: java, android, canvas, touch-event

Based on this answer, I created a arrayList of rectF.

[Technique to make a canvas drawLine() clickable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18275032/technique-to-make-a-canvas-drawline-clickable)

here's the logic of my code :

```
List<RectF> rectFs;

Point pt1;
Point pt2;
```

then

```
path.moveTo(pt1.x, pt1.y);
path.lineTo(pt2.x, pt2.y);

path.computeBounds(rectF, true);
rectFs.add(rectF);
```

and then, I have this method to check the clicked and the rectF arrayList.

```
void lineHighighted(Point pt) {
    int ct = 0;
    for(RectF rectF : rectFs) {
        if(rectF.contains(pt.x, pt.y)) {
            ct++;
            Log.d(tag, ct + "HERE");
        }
    }
}
```

my problem is, sometimes, the whole arraylist is selected or "called" even I didn't touch that "line".

Any wrong in my code?

Thanks in advance.

ADDITIONAL :

I found out that after adding this code in my canvas :

```
path.moveTo(coor1[0], coor1[1]);
path.lineTo(coor2[0], coor2[1]);
canvas.drawPath(path, paint2);
path.computeBounds(rectf, true);
```

my previous result :
[image: before adding the code]

it becomes like this :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It might be!Because i don't see your code of interaction with canvas ill post the code which fully working.The logic is that one line mustn't overlay another one in case to proper function.hope i could help you.

```
    // setting where I will draw the ImageView for taking pictures

    // rec is used for onInterceptTouchEvent. I pass this from the
    // highest to lowest layer so that when this area of the screen
    // is pressed, it ignores the TouchView events and passes it to
    // this activity so that the button can be pressed.
    rec.set((int)((double)mScreenWidth*.85),
            (int)((double)mScreenHeight*.10) ,
            (int)((double)mScreenWidth*.85)+mButtonDrawable.getMinimumWidth(), 
            (int)((double)mScreenHeight*.70)+mButtonDrawable.getMinimumHeight());
    mButtonDrawable = null;
```

By This Logic you can use whatever you want in this logic it lets click happen not being overlaid

Comment: thanks for the answer sir. I really appreciate it.
Is it okay if you could check my additional question on the top?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: sorry i can't load your image can you reupload them??please:)

Comment: I found out the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27697251/a-specific-variable-in-an-object-is-becoming-identical-in-a-list

it is like the path.computebounds(rectf, true) is the problem. did you encounter this?

Comment: Oh no never i had cross that problem