# Android draw fixed paths on ImageView with support multiple screens

Tags: android, kotlin, android-imageview

I have continents image and i need when user clicks on image detect which continent he is clicked.

I have tried collecting x y coordinates for every continent and when user clicks on image I check if user finger x y exists in my Paths like this:

```
val path = Path()
path.moveTo(409f, 1986f)
path.lineTo(414f, 1986f)
path.lineTo(418f, 1986f)
...
path.close()

val rectF = RectF()
path.computeBounds(rectF, true)
val r = Region()
r.setPath(path, Region(rectF.left.toInt(), rectF.top.toInt(), rectF.right.toInt(), rectF.bottom.toInt()))

ivMainMap?.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
    val point = Point()
    point.x = event.x.toInt()
    point.y = event.y.toInt()
    if (r.contains(point.x, point.y)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "South America", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
    return@setOnTouchListener true
}
```

but i faced issue with multiple screen sizes, after that i have tried collecting x y coordinates on 560 dpi screen and convert x y to new x y with current screen size density, like this:

```
private fun getExactX(x: Float): Float {
    val screenAdjust = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.densityDpi.toFloat() / 560f
    return ((x) * screenAdjust)
}

private fun getExactY(y: Float): Float {
    val screenAdjust = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.densityDpi.toFloat() / 560f
    return ((y) * screenAdjust)
}
```

but the issue still exist

[image: continents image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: How to check if a path contains touched point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588003/android-how-to-check-if-a-path-contains-touched-point)

Comment: hint: `RectF` is a rectangle, which does not meet the minimum requirements, for the shape of a continent ...while you'd obviously need five paths, instead of one. while you're drawing rectangles, this probably never will work as expected.

Comment: @MartinZeitler i don't want to check if path contains touched point i want to draw path in image with fixed xs and ys and support all screen sizes

Comment: @MartinZeitler I know i need 7 paths not 5 but i added one path here just for example

Comment: no matter if 5, 6, or 7... draw a thin line along the paths, to see where they are. one could even make these paths click-able: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18275032/technique-to-make-a-canvas-drawline-clickable (and even remove the background image).

Comment: Thank you Martin but i know how i can make path clickable but what i don't know how i can draw same path with same position on multiple screen sizes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a ratio multiplier:

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    screen_width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    ratio_multiplier = screen_width/720; // Or whatever your base screen size is.

Then that ratio_multiplier can be used for anything that needs resizing.
I use this in all my programs for resizing button, images, etc.
```

Comment: You should be able to use this for coordinate adjustments as well.

Comment: I have used this code like this
((x) *  (Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.widthPixels.toFloat() / 1440f))

and it's worked fine with two different screen sizes but i don't know if it's will work with other screen sizes.

Comment: It should work for all of them. I've emulated various sizes like watch-wear, tv, etc., also tried on various devices, and even flipped to landscape from portrait during an apps operation; so far so good. But I'm always open to any unforeseen possibilities.

Comment: It's works fine if android navigation bar visible if i hide it the issue will present 
Samsung galaxy a8 2018